# how to differentiate among different exceptions of same class?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest, ftpwebresponse

how to check whether its is login info exception or a connection lost exception if the the exceptions are form the same class?

```
private bool checkFileExists(string absoluteRemoteLocation)
{
      try
      {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(absoluteRemoteLocation);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Timeout = timeOut;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.username, this.password);
            request.GetResponse();
            return true;
      }
      catch(Exception e) //i want to check here
      {
            var g = e.ToString();
            return false;
      }
}
```

Comment: Have two different catch blocks, one for each type.

Comment: arent they both from the same type System.Net.WebException?

Comment: If you know the messages will differ in some specific way (say, one contains "login info") then you can use c#6 filter: `catch (exception e) where e.message.contains("login info") {}`

Comment: @BenKnoble Yes i could do that i was just hoping there is some better way to do this than working with string of exception message

Comment: Well the where filter might work with is...?

Comment: @BenKnoble new to this. A link to where filter or its use might be useful. thanks.

Comment: I cant find a good link but search c# exception filters. It appears i was wrong and they use an if directly following the catch, like `catch(Exception e) if (somecondition) {}`

Comment: @BenKnoble can you check the answer i just posted for this question

Comment: You shouldnt post a question as an answer, and that probably isnt the best way. Let me write up an answer at some point with the filter when i get to a computer.

Comment: @BenKnoble I am sorry. new to this

Comment: Thats alright. Thats why we teach

Comment: @BenKnoble can you plz post the response you were talking about

Comment: I got it up sorry it slipped my mind

Answer (score 1):

Use different `catch` block like this:

```
catch (System.TimeoutException e)
{
    var g = e.ToString();
    return false;
}

catch (System.Net.WebException e)
{
    var g = e.ToString();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `is` keyword of C#.

```
<!-- language: C# -->
catch (Exception e) {
    if (e is LoginInfoException) // do something
    else if (e is ConnectionLostException) // do something else
}
```

For reference, check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) link.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you want?

```
public class Program
{    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {           
                throw new ConnectionLostException();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            if (ex is LoginInfoException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("LoginInfoException");
            }
            else if (ex is ConnectionLostException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("ConnectionLostException");  
            }
        }
    }
}

public class LoginInfoException : WebException
{
   public String Message { get; set; }

}

public class ConnectionLostException : WebException
{
   public String Message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think you might be getting at something but this throws its own exception

Comment: Just check if response variable is null before u use it. I think this is the case with some httpstatuscodes

Comment: in both the cases i am interested in (ie. timeout and invalid login) response is null. What should i do?

Comment: Afk, in this case try @chaudharyp 's way.. Try the is operator inside catch block of web exception

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of a filter that will catch different exceptions. I don't know much about the hierarchy of exceptions you're dealing with, but this will allow you to filter what exceptions get caught where.

```
public class CatchExceptions
{
    public void SomeMethod ()
    {
        try
        {
            //some stuff that throws exceptions
        }
        catch (WebException e) if (e is LoginInfoException)
        {}
        catch (WebException e) if (e is ConnectionLostException)
        {}
    }
}
```

Obviously you'll have to figure out what you can use to filter the exceptions like so; it appears that the two examples I used above are not concrete types. You may need to do some restructuring to figure out how to differentiate between the two.